# Где можно найти словарь терминов программистов чтобы не придумывать названия переменным?

Tags: разработка-игр, терминология

Существует ли словарь программиста (интересует разработчика видеоигр), в котором собраны термины и их описание. Необходимо для того, чтобы не придумывать неправильные названия переменным и функциям.

Comment: Словарь английского языка, имхо

Comment: Читайте туториалы и статьи по темам - там все термины и будут.

Answer (score 5):

Интересная мысль, к примеру вы пишите программу которая вычисляет KW тепла необходимые для обогрева помещения, а в словаре есть `GetPizza` нужно не придумывать велосипеды, а осмысленно называть методы в зависимости от операции которую они выполняют. В таком случае методу мы присвоим имя: `GetCountKilowatts()` думаю `GetPizza` здесь не уместно.

Comment: я думаю тут нужен словарик со словами типа антиалиасинг, интерполяция, триангуляция и в этом роде